# Unable to display username in android

Tags: android

I am trying to display the name of the currently logged in user. First time when I log in with the credentials, the user's name get displayed. But when I go back and again click on log in button(this time I need not enter the credentials since the last log in session is already on) the user's name isn't displayed.

Thanks in advance.

Here's the code for your reference.

login.java

```
SharedPreferences settings=getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
if(settings.getString("logged","").toString().equals("logged"))
{
     Intent intent=new Intent(login.this,gameHome.class);
     startActivity(intent);
}

login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
            String s1=username_login.getText().toString();
            String s2=password_login.getText().toString();

            if(s1.equals(""))
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter your username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else if(s2.equals(""))
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter your password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
            {
                Boolean username=db.checkUsername(s1);
                Boolean password=db.checkPassword(s2);

                if(username==true && password==true)
                {
                    SharedPreferences settings=getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("logged", "logged");
                    editor.commit();

                    username_login.setText("");
                    password_login.setText("");
                    Intent intent=new Intent(view.getContext(),gameHome.class);
                    intent.putExtra("user_name",s1);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid username or password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                }
        }
    });
```

gameHome.java

```
TextView txt;
String username;

txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.game_home_username);

username = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_name");
txt.setText(username);
```

Comment: Everything is right in this code, are you sure your xml is perfect?? or can you provide some more code?

Answer (score 0):

**At start**

```
SharedPreferences settings=getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);

if(!settings.getString("user_name", "").equals("")){
    Intent intent=new Intent(login.this, gameHome.class);
    String userName = settings.getString("user_name", "");
    intent.putExtra("user_name",userName);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**In Login**

```
if(username==true && password==true) {
    SharedPreferences settings=getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=settings.edit();
    editor.putString("user_name", s1);

    editor.commit();
    Intent intent=new Intent(view.getContext(),gameHome.class);
    intent.putExtra("user_name",s1);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: String s1 = settings.getString("user_name");  //This line isn't helping. Please help.

Comment: String s1 = settings.getString("user_name"); 

 within settings.getString(), two arguments are required. But am passing only one which is causing the error. And am not getting exactly as to what should be the second argument.

Secondly, I tried with this one:
 if(!settings.getString("user_name", null).equals(null))
But even this is throwing me a run time error of NullPointerException

Comment: Please check my last solution, if not works, findme in the chat in forodev.com.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are not saving the username In `SharedPreference` .You just passing the username once when user logged in ,that's why username disappears . 
So Firstly Save the username in `Shareprefernce` then if `shareprefernce` is not null retrive the username .

So to save the username use this method:

```
intent.putExtra("user_name",s1);
```

To get the username from SharedPreference :

```
    SharedPreferences settins = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Youractivity.this);
     pref1=settings.getString("user_name");
     txt.setText(pref1);
```